# I need to edit the rails gemsfile, where is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I'm installing Ruby on Windows 10.
I already installed Ruby 2.3
When I tried to install Rails 4.2.6 I had problems with nokogiri.

Thanks to this [questions and answers](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1456) I was able to solve by installing nokogiri version 1.6.6.4 then rails then version 1.6.8.rc3 like this:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.4'
gem install rails 
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.rc3'
```

But after that, I'm supposed to include this:

```
gem 'nokogiri', '>=1.6.8.rc3'
```

in gemfile.

When asked, the guys says:

> Hey, guys, just add `gem 'nokogiri', '>=1.6.8.rc3` in your Rails
>   application Gemfile (outside of the development, test, production
>   group) and `run bundle update nokogiri`.

But I'm not sure where is the Rails application gemfile or which file should I edit.
From [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762590/rails-gemfile-editing) I can see how the file content is but there isnt much explanation about where do I find it.

I'm about to take a tutorial in Ruby o Rails, so I'm below noob, and the first page tutorial is about installing Ruby and Rails, it's supposed to install easy except for the nokigiri problem (only a Windows problem it seems).

Comment: After installing the `rails` gem, you have to create a new rails application using the [`rails new`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-new) command. It creates a directory structure, including a Gemfile (every application has its own Gemfile). See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Does it means that the gemfile must be modified for every project for nokogiri to work?

Comment: I don't know, this seems to be a Windows-specific problem (I'm not running Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Gemfile` is typically located in the root of your project and is called just that `Gemfile`.

Don't change the `Gemfile.lock` file it is written automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a file with name 'Gemfile' at the root of your rails application.

Answer (score 1):

"The Rails application gemfile" is the file called `Gemfile`, in the root of your project.

You have already pasted the contents of this file in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762590/rails-gemfile-editing).